# Push ViewController subviews beneath NavigationBar when translucent is True, Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

This question asked to be implemented in Swift 4, iOS 11

Is there any way to make every subview of ViewController's view to be pushed down when it is under UINavigationBar?

If navigation bar is NOT TRANSLUCENT the subview is under it. This is what I want.

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tR4z.png)

But when navigation bar is TRANSLUCENT the subview is lying under it. I dont want it. I want the subview is pushed down just be like if navigation bar is not translucent.

[Undesired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1hXA.png)

I create the view programmatically :

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        let navBar = (self.parent as? UINavigationController)?.navigationBar
        navBar?.isTranslucent = true
    }

    func makeChildView() {
        let myframe = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 
    self.view.frame.height * 0.4)
        let view = UIView(frame: myframe)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }
```

## Using Autolayout

I am able to solve this problem using autolayout. But I just want to know how to achieve this result without autolayout if possible. Is there any other approach?

Comment: Please use markdown for your code instead of using images.

Comment: Sure, let me write it. I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.x**

```
navBar?.isTranslucent = true
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Add this line & you are good to go.

Comment: `self.automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets` is deprecated in iOS 11. I find this such answer in every question but because its not work for me, then I need another solution.